# Dart importing 3rd party libary causes build errors

Tags: angular, import, dart, dart-js-interop

I am writing a component where I have to use the 3rd party ckeditor.
And If I import the editor's js and try to build it will cause this error:

`Build error:
Transform DirectiveMetadataLinker on WebstormProjectsWYSIWIG_editor|lib/CKE_component.ng_summary.json threw error: Invalid argument (uri): Provided value ends with an unexpected extension. Expected extension(s): [.dart.deferredCount, .ng_meta.json, .ng_summary.json, .template.dart, .dart].: "ckeditor/ckeditor.js"`

Comment: What does "And If I import the editor's js" mean exactly?

Comment: It means that If I try to use the <code> import 'ckeditor.js'; </code> the error occurs.

Comment: How is that "importing"? `<code>` is to show source verbatim at the web page.

Comment: It says:
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:63342/wrapper/web/packages/wrapper/app_component.template.dart
And:
An error occurred loading file: package:wrapper/app_component.template.dart

Comment: I still don't get what you try to accomplish can haven't found any info that would allow me to diagnose what's going on.

Comment: I try to use a javascript libary with dart/angular2.

Comment: I guess I can't help you. I don't see any relation between the error message and adding JS.